# Tweepy - fetching tweets without filter

Tags: filter, tweepy

In tweepy streaming API, I want to collect tweets with location filter. Thus I have used the following command.

```
stream.filter()
```

I also need to collect tweets without a location filter. For this, I have used the following command.

```
stream.sample()
```

Logically, I think the sample() function should retrieve a larger number of tweets. But my observation is that sample() is fetching much lesser number of tweets. Is it supposed to be this way? How can I fetch all tweets without applying location filter?

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed search for tweets in a specific location, with a specific hashtag, user, ...
But you can't search for every tweet created. There is too much data to get.

You need to specify a filter. 
So it depends on the tweets you need to get.

You can use *userstream()* to get tweets tweeted to you and only you. 
You can use *filter(track=[somefilter])* to get tweets from research with the specified filter